# KQl- RowCumsum detection

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

| UserId | T | status | StatusDuration(seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-20T17:09:33.572Z | RUNNING | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-03-20T17:09:28.572Z | RUNNING | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-20T17:09:23.568Z | Idle | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-20T17:09:18.628Z | stop | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-20T17:09:13.564Z | RUNNING | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-03-20T17:09:08.56Z | offline | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-03-20T17:09:03.764Z | offline | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-03-20T17:08:58.556Z | offline | 10 |
| 2 | 2023-03-20T17:08:53.596Z | RUNNING | 10 |
| 2 | 2023-03-20T17:08:48.552Z | Idle | 10 |

In above table have two  userIds, within the userIds if status changing from one  to another   status at very first then remaining records in the userIds has the same  time(T) difference when the first status changed timedifference  ,, How to find the StatusDuration for like above ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used sample data posted in question to create a table and used below code to calculate value for **
StatusDuration(seconds)** column.

**Code/Query**

```
let  tbl = datatable(UserId: string, T: datetime , Status: string )
[
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:33.572Z), "RUNNING",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:28.572Z), "RUNNING",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:23.568Z), "Idle",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:18.628Z),"stop",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:13.564Z),"RUNNING",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:08.56Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:03.764Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:58.556Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:53.596Z), "RUNNING",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:48.552Z), "Idle"
];
tbl
| serialize
| order  by  T
| extend  a = UserId != prev(UserId)
| extend ["StatusDuration(seconds)"] = case (a == true ,0 ,datetime_diff('second',prev(T),T) )
| project-away  a;
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Wrong answer please check still appreciate your effort, I found the solution myself

Answer (score -1):

let  tbl = datatable(UserId: string, T: datetime , Status: string )
[
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:33.572Z), "RUNNING",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:28.572Z), "RUNNING",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:23.568Z), "Idle",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:18.628Z),"stop",
1,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:13.564Z),"RUNNING",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:08.56Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:09:03.764Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:58.556Z), "offline",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:53.596Z), "RUNNING",
2,datetime(2023-03-20T17:08:48.552Z), "Idle"
];
tbl
| serialize
| partition  hint.strategy= native  by UserId
(
order  by  T desc
| extend  batchId = row_rank(Status)
| where batchId  == 1
| extend ["Duration status"] =  row_cumsum(iff(UserId== prev(UserId) and Status  == prev(Status),datetime_diff('second',prev(T),T),0))
)

[image]

Comment: Please pay attention to code formatting and also add an explanation to help future readers understand how this answers the question.